# How can I Allocate More Space to a Filesystem Mounted on /?

Tags: filesystems, fdisk

I am new to Linux so please forgive the incorrect use of vocabulary.

My company has a private cloud that provisions VM's in a KVM. I received a RHEL 6.4. When I provisioned it, I asked for 50GB of additional storage.

Here is the results of `df -h`:

[image]

The filesystem /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root mounted on `/` is full. After consulting my companies FAQ, I found one called "Where is my extra storage that I ordered with my VM?" and was directed to  a PDF that showed me how to create a new filesystem mounted on a new directory called `/data`. I was unable to determine how to simply extend the fileysystem mounted on `/`. I did that on a different VM as a test.

On the VM which I wish to extend the filesystem mounted on `/`, here are the results of `fdisk -l`:

[image]

Here are the results for `pvdisplay`:

[image]

On a test VM I issued the following commands as specified by my companies FAQ:

```
pvcreate /dev/vdb
vgcreate DATAVG /dev/sdb
lvcreate -L 10G -n lvdata1 DATAVG
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/DATAVG/lvdata1
tune2fs -c0 -i0 /dev/DATAAVG/lvdata1
```

I appended the following to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/DATAVG/lvdata1    /data    ext4    defaults    1 2
```

and then mounted `/data`:

```
mount /data
```

After this, a `df -h` results in:

[image]

This shows that I can successfully add storage, but I wish to add the storage to the filesystem mounted on `/` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first you need to unmount the second device again, before you proceed with the following steps:

You will have to add the device `/dev/vdb` into your logical volume group `VolGroup`, you can do this using `vgextend`.

```
vgextend VolGroup /dev/vdb
```

After this you can first grow the logical volume `lv_root` to the size of the group, using `lvextend`.

```
lvextend /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root -L+49G
```

Then you need to grow the file system on the logical volume with `fsadm`.

```
fsadm resize /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

Here are more details about resizing the file system: [grow file system](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-use-logical-volume-manager-lvm-to-grow-etx4-file-systems-online/)

Comment: Hi Mauro. I issued `umount /data` and confirmed it with `df`. However, the `vgextend VolGroup /dev/vdb` resulted in `Physical volume '/dev/vdb' is already in volume group 'DATAVG' Unable to add physical volume '/dev/vdb' to volume group 'VolGroup'.` How may I rectify that? I assume it got that way from when I issued `vgcreate DATAVG /dev/sdb`

Comment: I also have another VM that I can start over again from `pvcreate /dev/vdb`

Comment: you need to completely free up `/dev/vdb` first. This means delete the logical volume `lvdata1` that you created in the group `DATAVG`, and then delete the group `DATAVG`.

Comment: Ok I issued `lvremove DATAVG` and `vgremove DATAVG`. I was then able to issue `vgextend VolGroup /dev/vdb`. however the `lvextend /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root +49G` resulted in `Physical Volume "+49G" not found in Volume Group "VolGroup"` Did you mean `lvextend /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root -L+49G`? That worked for me. I have just entered `fsadm resize /dev/mapper/VolGroup -lv_root` and am awaiting the result.

Comment: and now df -h shows the filesystem mounted on `/` as having increased 50G! Thank you! Would you please edit your `lvextend` comand to include `-L+49G` instead of `+49G` ?

Comment: Oh, right, I've missed the `-L` in `lvextend`. Great that it worked